# Conversion of code from .net framework1.1 to 2.0

Tags: .net

Is there any better way for converting code written in .net framework 1.1 to framework 2.0 rather than manually checking entire application and changing individually

Comment: Can you give examples of something that you'd need automated? Adding referneces to System.Configuration? Converithng Web Applicaiton Projects to Web Site Projects? [Then you'll get my +1 :P]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Visual Studio will try to do all that it can, when you open the project with Visual Studio 2005 or 2008. However you'll still have to fix some parts manually.

Especially when it's a web application.

You might want to review your application for things like ArrayLists and replace them with List<> and other .NET 2.0 constructs (be careful if you do, this could result in a lot of work).

Comment: Sure,,Is there any tool for the conversion

Comment: Re web applications - the problem is when you're using VS2005 without the Web Application project addin (which IIRC is in SP1). In that case, you get converted to a web site and generally lots of confusion. If you dont do that migration, you dont experience the same level of deep pain.

Comment: I don't think a tool would be that helpful. An Arraylist for example can contain any type of object, it's hard to infer what the actual type should be. Refactoring could save you some time.

Answer (score 1):

Why would you do it manually?

Just load it into newer version of Visual Studio. It will leave you with report of what was converted and where possible issues could be. I used it on quite a few projects and had no issues (once you check each item on report).

Comment: Sure,,Is there any tool for the conversion

Comment: I am not aware of such tool. Visual Studio does great job of converting it and if it says in report that you need to check something.